# How can we call a class of bootstrap from javascript and design our own content field of popover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
           trigger: 'click',
           'placement': 'bottom', 
           html: true, content:" " 
    });
});
```

how can we call css class of bootstrap in this content field of the popover .

Comment: You can add a click, hover (mouse event) to your button/action and apply classes via `addClass()` or `toggleClass()`. You can also use an inspector, like Chrome dev tools (f12) or firebug to inspect the classes applied to the bootstrap popover, and modify as needed.

Comment: can you show the syntax how to call the any dummy class in  the content of above javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic format for adding HTML content:

```
var title = 'Oh, hello there...';
var htmlcontent = '<p>Here is some custom <strong>HTML</strong> content.</p>';

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    title: title,
    content: htmlcontent,
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true
});
```

You can also customize the popover template, but the template must have the following basic elements:

```
<div class="popover" role="tooltip"> <!--Outermost wrapper element with .popover class -->
  <div class="arrow"></div> <!--Creates the arrow -->
  <h3 class="popover-title"></h3> <!--Title is injected here (this is optional) -->
  <div class="popover-content"></div> <!--Content is injected here (not optional)-->
</div>
```

If using a custom template, don't try and add the title or content directly in the template, it will just be overwritten with whatever is set as the content and title in the options or the data-content/title attributes in the markup.  If you do not provide any content value, the popover will simply fail.

The demo shows examples of both using the standard template to inject custom html content, as well as using a customized template.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/QtW7d/)